# casting of an int to vector in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I've seen this piece of code and had a hard time understanding how casting a `int` to a `vector<int>` could possibly have worked!

```
 std::vector<int> v = static_cast<std::vector<int>>(10);
 cout << v.size(); // this prints 10
```

From my understanding, an int is sort of one dimensional, so to speak, whereas a vector is two dimensional.

How can one possibly be cast to another? And if it is possible, I can see a least a dozen ways an int can be cast to a collection of it. Why does this instance choose "size"? Is this some built-in convention?

Comment: This is just an unnecessarily elaborate way to write `std::vector<int> v(10);` Whoever wrote the original didn't quite know what they were doing, it would seem; or else was intentionally obfuscating. Anyway, it uses [overload (3) here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Dimension isn't a C++ concept so it is actually unrelated to your question. Besides, I think scalar is 0th order, and vector is 1st order.

Answer (score 4):

> How can one possibly be cast to another?

```
static_cast<T>(a);
```

is valid if `a` can be used to construct an instance of `T`.

It is equivalent to:

```
T(a);
```

From the [C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast#4):

> 4 Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t`.

In your case, it is valid since `std::vector` has the following constructor:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

---

**PS**

The line

```
 std::vector<int> v = static_cast<std::vector<int>>(10);
```

can be simplified to

```
 std::vector<int> v(10);
```

It's hard telling why the person who wrote that line of code thought of writing it that way.